# Is there a (working) iTunes 11 "search" shortcut?

Tags: itunes, windows

The Help Topics say that Ctrl+Alt+F should go to the search field, but it don't here. I'm on Windows 7, with iTunes 11.

Is there a shortcut for the search? (I really don't like to have to use the mouse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem here, but I have the answer: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>

Comment: Hey... that works now. I thought I tried every combination with "f" last time... anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Windows install handy to test, but the OS X version did change the shortcut from <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> to just <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>. The equivalent Windows shortcut would likely be <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>.

Comment: No, I tried every combination with "f" or "s".